# Creating a cookie in IOS for writing unit tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies

I need to write a unit test for getting all cookies and clearing them for an ios device. For this I wanted to create my own array of cookies and pass this to the method which does the task of clearing the cookies. I created a cookie using the method [NSHTTPCookie :initwithProperties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookie/initWithProperties:). But when i print the cookie the value is somehow null -

Here's the code to it :

[image]

The NSLog prints `Cookie (null)` and I have no idea why this is.

Comment: Try removing the `@""` surrounding the `NSHTTPCookiePath ...` I believe those are defined constants.

Comment: Hey @Bair Thanks so much You are awesome. I never thought something like this. I plainly thought that as it is a dictionary it would work this way. It worked. :)

Comment: Np. It's understandable. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments:

> Try removing the `@""` surrounding the `NSHTTPCookiePath ...` I believe those are defined constants.